# Operator overloading, need an explanation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

There is this code:

```
 class precision {   
       int digits;
       public:   precision(int digits) : digits(digits) {}
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const precision& p) {
           os.precision(p.digits);
           return os;
       }
   };
```

It's meant to make a command line like:

```
cout << precision(5) << a << " " << precision(2) << b << endl;
```

to work, instead of doing:

```
cout.precision(5);
cout << a << " ";
cout.precision(2);
cout << b << endl
```

I fail to understand how the friend function part works. Why is it a friend? And how come it receives two arguments instead of one? THanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a friend so that it can access the private value `digits`.

The two arguments come from the compiler matching `cout << precision(5)` to a call `operator<<(cout, precision(5))`. The operator then returns a refence to the stream, which is used for the next part `stream << a`, etc.